# Simple question using Dash, how do i display the updated output of a variable?

Tags: python, variables, callback, plotly-dash

New to Dash so bear with.

I have a websocket connection that streams forex data to my console; price, high, low, symbol etc.

I'd like to have that information displayed on a dashboard that is easily viewable, instead of everything being printed to my console.

The issue i face is the data only updates on page refresh, when i'd like it to update as it is received, on the dashboard.

This is my code to connect to the websocket and create the dashboard:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import fxcmpy
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import time

con = fxcmpy.fxcmpy(access_token = "1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111212", log_level = 'error')

currenc = ["AUD/CAD", "AUD/CHF", "AUD/JPY", "AUD/NZD", "AUD/USD", "CAD/CHF", "CAD/JPY", "CHF/JPY", "EUR/AUD", "EUR/CAD", "EUR/CHF", "EUR/GBP", "EUR/JPY", "EUR/NZD", "EUR/TRY", "EUR/USD", "GBP/AUD", "GBP/CAD", "GBP/CHF", "GBP/JPY", "GBP/NZD", "GBP/USD", "NZD/CAD", "NZD/CHF", "NZD/JPY", "NZD/USD", "USD/CAD", "USD/JPY"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

def print_data(data, dataframe):

    t = pd.to_datetime(int(data['Updated']), unit='ms')
    price = data['Rates'][0]
    symbol = data['Symbol']

    app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.Textarea(
            id='textprice',
            value=(str(price)),
            style={'width': '100%', 'height': 300},
        ),
        dcc.Textarea(
            id='textsymbol',
            value=(str(symbol)),
            style={'width': '100%', 'height': 300},
        ),
        html.Div(id='textarea-example-output', style={'whiteSpace': 'pre-line'})
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in currenc:
        con.subscribe_market_data(i, (print_data,))
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The dashboard contains two text boxes, one for price, the other for symbol. I'd like to be able to have the dashboard open and those values update automatically.

Any help will be appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [Interval](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/interval) component. Set up the `dcc.Interval` for whatever time period you want, and use it as the input to a callback function. The output from that function will be the text boxes with the data you want to refresh each time the interval updates. Very basically:

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    ...
    dcc.Interval(id='my-interval', interval=5000),  # one tick each 5 seconds
    html.Div(id='my-output', children=[]),
    ...
])


@app.callback(Output('my-output', 'children'),
              [Input('my-interval', 'n_intervals')])
def callback_func(interval):
    # make your calls to get the data

    return [html.Div([
        # the data content in here
    ])
```